# grep - the multiline pattern writing

Tags: command-line, grep

How can I write `grep` pattern in multiple lines, inside `bash` script? Like that:

```
grep -o -P '
    (?!<.*?(?<!(href))=")
        https?:\/\/(?!(www\.example\.com)).*?
    (?=(">))
' input.txt
```

When I wrote `php` programs, I could do so. Now tried this in the bash script - it doesn't work. It is very unhandy write all in one line :(

May be exist option, which allows formatting inside pattern, that is, `grep` doesn't notice whitespaces (spaces and newlines), when this option is enabled.

**grep version:**

```
grep -V
grep (GNU grep) 2.25
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` takes newlines as separating different patterns. But you could save the pattern in a variable, and then remove the whitespace before passing it to `grep`:

```
$ ws=$' \t\n'
$ pat=$'a b\nc'
$ echo abcd | grep "${pat//[$'\n\t ']}"
abcd
```

(Didn't test with anything more complex.)

Answer (score 4):

Even with `-P` which enables `(?x:)` you can't ignore newlines. For spaces and tabs, it works:

```
echo abab | grep -P $'(?x:a b a\tb)'
```

But newline doesn't work the same way:

```
echo ab | grep -P $'(?x:a\nb)'
grep: the -P option only supports a single pattern
```

At least in GNU grep 2.16.

Comment: Isn't that a bug? It seems distinctly not perl-compatible.

Comment: Same with inline comments (`(?# inline comment)`); it cannot have newlines inside it (GNU grep 3.4). `grep` automatically splits a single pattern argument on newlines, and that feature interferes with the PCRE feature of allowing whitespace in a lot of places. Too bad indeed.